# Having trouble downloading Ubuntu 20.04 iso

Tags: 20.04, downloads

Every time I try downloading Ubuntu, it starts to download, then keeps saying “Failed - Network error”. Works fine with some of the other official Ubuntu flavors but the default Ubuntu download from https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop won't finish.

Comment: To the [torrent downloads](https://ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads) if you want. They have the added benefit of verifying the download's integrity for you automatically.

Comment: This happened to me in a web browser on a slow connection, but not with the command line (I think I used `curl`) maybe try that.

Answer (score 1):

1. **GUI Solution:** You can install and use [FDM](https://www.freedownloadmanager.org/download-fdm-for-linux.htm) as your download manager and download file using this.
2. **Non GUI Solution:** Or using `curl` from the command line.
3. **Torrent Solution:**  Use Transmission and BitTorrent file available in [Alternative downloads](https://ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads). Although FDM can download torrent files.